# ngTransclude doesnt render content correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

Trying to dynamically pass error/feedback messages to a directive through Transclude. However the transcluded content doesnt redner corrrectly either due to the tag span or the `innerForm.inputField.$error.....`

EDIT: text between brackets [text] is test that needs to be translated. Dont be confused by that.

Cant find info about limitations about transcluding content. Hope to get some pointers here.

The Directive tag in the DOM

```
<input-validation-below
          place-holder="[E-mail address]"
          identifier="forgotten_email"
          ng-model="email"
          type="email">

      <span data-ng-show="innerForm.inputField.$error.required">[E-mail address] [is required]</span>
      <span data-ng-show="innerForm.inputField.$error.email">[This is not a valid] [E-mail address]</span>

    </input-validation-below>
```

The Directive

```
angular.module('inputValidationBelow', []).directive('inputValidationBelow', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            login: '=ngModel',
            placeHolder: '@',
            identifier: '@',
            type: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/inputValidationBelow/inputValidationBelow.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        require: ['ngModel', '^form'],
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

            scope.type = attrs.type;

            var ngModelController = controllers[0];
            ngModelController.$render = function () {
                if (typeof ngModelController.$viewValue !== 'undefined') {
                    scope.login = ngModelController.$viewValue;
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

The Directive template

```
<ng-form name="innerForm"
    <label class="full-width" for="inputField" data-ng-class="{ error: innerForm.inputField.$dirty && innerForm.inputField.$invalid }">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><p>{{placeHolder}}:</p></p><![endif]-->
        <input class="form full-width" type="{{type}}" name="inputField" placeholder="{{placeHolder}}" id="inputField" data-ng-model="login[identifier]" required />
    </label>

    <div class="alert alert-input" data-ng-show="innerForm.inputField.$dirty && innerForm.inputField.$invalid">
        <span class="alert alert-input" ng-transclude></span>
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

**--EDIT--**

adding this line to the Link function `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` "fixes" the issue but gives me an error:

`Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <span class="alert alert-input" ng-transclude="">`

Comment: plnk would be helpful

Comment: Doesn't render correctly means what? `innerForm` is only available in the directive's scope.

Comment: since innerForm is content thats gonna be transcluded it will end up in the Directive scope, right? Mybe it needs to recompile the template after transcluding?

Comment: This question is old but I'm facing same issue right now. To make it clear, the `<div ng-messages></div>` gets rendered, but the child `<div ng-message>some message</div>` divs don't